# Access form inside controller

Tags: angularjs

Here is my full code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>  
</head>


<body >
 <div ng-controller="myController">                        
 <form name="myForm">
   <input ng-model="option" name="test">
   {{myForm.$dirty}}
   <button>Save</button>
 </form>
 </div>



 <script> 
 angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myController',function($scope){

    $scope.option=2;
    console.log($scope.myForm);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

While `{{myForm.$dirty}}` works, `console.log($scope.myForm)` returns **undefined**!!! At the same time if I `console.log($scope)` I can see `myForm` as one of its properties!!!!  As not to go mad, could someone explain this paradox?

Comment: if instead of your current console.log write `window.setTimeout(function() { console.log($scope.myForm) })` it's defined - it's just not defined at the very instant the controller is initialized

Comment: You have to wait until the view is loaded to have anything in the form. re you using State or Location to handle your routing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this solution, but it works.  Put a $timeout around the code that you would like to access the form. The $timeout kind of forces the code to wait until the form is fully rendered. (Don't forget to inject $timeout.)

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myController',function($scope, $timeout){

$scope.option=2;
$timeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.myForm);
}); //Note that you don't need it to actually wait for any amount of time
```

The reason why you see the form if you console.log($scope) but not when you console.log($scope.myForm), is because the console will evaluate $scope when you expand it. By then, the form has rendered and attached to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a watcher on the form ? I'm guessing that the form is simply not yet defined when the controller code is defined.

```
$scope.$watch('myForm', function(form) {
  if(form) {
    //check if form is defined
  }
});
```